# A Question about C++ / OOD Interview Questions

Tags: c++, oop, ooad

1. What is the most interesting or difficult question asked to you during an C++/OOD interview?
2. What is the most interesting or difficult question you like to ask to a candidate during a C++/OOD interview?

Edit: Updated the misleading Title
Edit: Ofcourse:
 1. When you are the one being interviewed.
 2. When you are intervieweing someone.

Comment: They ask you about interviews during your interviews? How meta.

Comment: @BoltClock: Maybe he was interviewing for an interviewer position. Talk about a tough sell!

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: Those ar e2 separate questions and hence marked 1 and 2. The two are difference scnearios, 1. when you are the candidate and 2. when you are the interviewer.

Comment: Now that you clarified your question, I think this is a little off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it isn't as technical as actual C++/OOD interview questions. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BoltClock: Intention was to find interesting/difficult questions and then discuss possible and best answers on them. Well never mind, guess most of the peeps were in too much hurry(eager) to close this one.